# Do I need to use name attributes when validating a bootstrap form with jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Still kind of new and I just started using bootstrap but basically when using stock HTML I see name attributes being used like so

```
<label for="email" class="label">E-mail Address</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
```

but with bootstrap there is typically no name attr used.

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword-" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I guess i'm just confused where the jquery validator is pulling information from. Does the email refer to the name attr or the label for?

```
    rules: {
      email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator uses the `name` attribute to find the field, as all form elements *must* have a name attribute.

The second block of HTML code you've posted is not valid for that reason.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this answer to clarify some ambiguous and misleading information posted within another's answer.

**Quote Title:**

> *"Do I need to use name attributes when validating a bootstrap form with jQuery Validation plugin?"*

It does not matter what kind of form.  When using the jQuery Validation plugin, any **data input elements that are to be validated *must* each contain a unique `name` attribute, period... no workarounds, no exceptions.**  *(The `name` attribute is the only way the jQuery Validation plugin can keep track of the data input elements being validated.)*

This means that you cannot get around this requirement by using the `.rules('add')` method.  I've seen this touted more than once on SO as a proposed workaround for elements without a `name` attribute.  This will not work.  *No matter how rules are declared*, the data input elements *must* still have a `name` attribute.

**Demo without `name` attributes (broken validation):  http://jsfiddle.net/L3u5n/**

**Identical demo, but with `name` attributes (working validation): http://jsfiddle.net/L3u5n/1/**

---

See the "**Markup recommendations**" section of [the "**Reference docs**" page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/).

> *"The `name` attribute is '**required**' for input elements, the validation plugin **doesn't work** without it."*

Answer (score 0):

`name` is must in the `form` element and you need it for `jQuery validator` too

---

you can also use `jQuery validator` like this

[.rules( “add”, rules )](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#rules-%22add%22-rules)

```
$("el").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    email: true
});
```

Comment: exellent, this will help

Comment: Your answer is somewhat ambiguous:  _"`name` is [a] must in the `form` element"_. ~ No matter how you assign the rules, `name` is a must for every input element being validated, and `name` is not a must for the `form` element itself.

Comment: @Sparky I have written `name is must in the form element`  in line one and i have given user option to assign rule using `jQuery validator `

Comment: Except that using `rules()` method does not negate the need for the `name` attribute on each input element.   Like I said, your answer is unclear at best.

Comment: [I don't believe in editing the meaning of somebody else's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64843/157574)... at that point, there's no reason not to post [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20168104/594235).