# Validation based on field id rather than field name with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

By default jQuery validation plugin validates form fields based on name of the field.

I want the plugin need validate based on field id.

http://bassistance.de/2013/03/22/release-validation-plugin-1-11-1/

Comment: There is no way to do this without the `name` attribute, period. The jQuery Validate plugin needs the `name` attribute to keep track of the input elements. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140588/do-i-need-to-use-name-attributes-when-validating-a-bootstrap-form-with-jquery-va/20168104#20168104

Answer (score 2):

It is possible through the add rule method: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: It need to add rules for every input fields. But I need modify plugin to validate based on id instead of name.

Answer (score 2):

> One thing is sure that the `name` of the input fields must be unique other wise validation is gonna apply to single field only.

you can use item index ( random or serial numbers ) to make the the names unique.

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="bids[spec_attributes][0][name]" /><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="bids[spec_attributes][1][size]"/><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="bids[spec_attributes][2][email]"/><br/>

    <input type="text" name="bids[spec_attributes][10][name]" /><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="bids[spec_attributes][11][size]"/><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="bids[spec_attributes][12][email]"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate();
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
      $(this).rules('add', {
          required: true
      });
    });

});
```

have a look to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjqvnnho/1/